# Duplicate NSView at runtime

Tags: objective-c, nsview, nspopover

Is it possible to duplicate a NSView at runtime? I use it as a popover showing text messages and I'd like to show it "twice" (with different messages) simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

If you create the `NSPopover` instance programmatically, then you can define the `NSView` in a nib of its own (that is the simplest way to create an `NSPopover` anyway) and then just instantiate two different `NSViewControllers` with the same nib file.